# Как вызвать SOAP WSDL сервис из curl?

Tags: curl, soap, wsdl

А как вызвать сервис soap wsdl из curl?

```
http://saptest.ru:8000/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/flv_1000111AD1/bndg_url/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/z00_rgp_extr_uni3/200/z00_rgp_extr_uni3/z00_rgp_extr_uni3?sap-client=200

login TEST1
psw pass1

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:urn="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <urn:Z00_RGP_EXTR_UNI3>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <IF_DEL_ZERO></IF_DEL_ZERO>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <IF_DOWNLOAD></IF_DOWNLOAD>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <IF_ZIP></IF_ZIP>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <IT_WHERE>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:
            <item>
              <FIELDNM></FIELDNM>
               <SIGN></SIGN>
               <OPT></OPT>
               <LOW></LOW>
               <HIGH></HIGH>
               <LOGICOP></LOGICOP>
               <REF_NUM></REF_NUM>
            </item>
-->
 
         </IT_WHERE>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <I_FILEPATH></I_FILEPATH>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <I_OUT_FORMAT>JSON</I_OUT_FORMAT>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <I_SEL_DT>TD</I_SEL_DT>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <I_SEL_ID>K1</I_SEL_ID>
      </urn:Z00_RGP_EXTR_UNI3>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

При вызове через curl возникает ошибка:

```
Запрос:
    curl --user TEST1:pass1 --header "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" --header "SOAPAction:Get" --data @test.xml http://saptest.ru:8000/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/flv_1000111AD1/bndg_url/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/z00_rgp_extr_uni3/200/z00_rgp_extr_uni3/z00_rgp_extr_uni3?sap-client=200

Ошибка:
    <env:Fault xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><env:Code><env:Value>env:Sender</env:Value></env:Code><env:Reason><env:Text xml:lang="en">Invalid WSDL access, no SOAP request expected</env:Text></env:Reason><env:Detail><description><text>An HTTP POST request with a SOAP request in the body was send to a WSDL URL. To call the web service use the service URL instead of the WSDL URL. To access the WSDL use an HTTP GET request or send the request with an empty HTTP body.</text></description></env:Detail></env:Fault>%
```

Answer (score 0):

Вроде английским по белому жалуется что нужно использовать POST запрос а не GET. Пробуйте

```
  curl -X POST --user TEST1:pass1 --header "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" --header "SOAPAction:Get" --data @test.xml http://saptest.ru:8000/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/flv_1000111AD1/bndg_url/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/z00_rgp_extr_uni3/200/z00_rgp_extr_uni3/z00_rgp_extr_uni3?sap-client=200
```

кроме того проверьте что URL соответствует эндпоинту сервиса а не самой wsdl